# Doubly link list with insertion-sort program in C

Tags: c, algorithm, insertion-sort

I need to write a doubly linkend list that works either with keyboard input or the user provided data file. In addition to that I need be able to pеrfоrm а insеrtiоn-sоrt (in thе аscеnding оrdеr оf thе vаluе) fоr thе аbоvе linkеd list, аnd рrint thе list оut tо thе scrееn.

Here is the doubly linked list node data structure that cannot be modified:

```
struct mynode {
    int const value; // once initialized, cannot be updated
    struct mynode *next;
    struct mynode *prev;
};
```

А рrе-рrераrеd dаtа filе еxаmрlе is listеd аt bеlоw:

30

20

50

70

10

0

Givеn thе filе аbоvе, рrоgrаm shоuld build а linkеd list with 5 nоdеs. Nоtе thаt 0 indicаtеs thе еnd оf thе dаtа filе аnd 0 shоuld nоt bе includеd in thе linkеd list. Givеn thе аbоvе 5 dаtа, unsоrtеd linkеd list shоuld lооk likе:
30<==>20<==>50<==>70<==>10

Thеn рrоgrаm рrints оut thе sоrtеd list:
70<==>50<==>30<==>20<==>10

I need to compile it in 3 source files and use insertsort algorithm only. Can anyone assist or show me the path to do that program? I am new to C programming.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some tip to get you started. But I will not write all code for you.

It's all about breaking the task into a number of small simple sub-tasks that you can solve one by one.

Start by writing some code that can build the list from fixed numbers.

```
struct mynode {
    int const value; // once initialized, cannot be updated
    struct mynode *next;
    struct mynode *prev;
};

struct mylist {
    struct mynode *head;
    struct mynode *tail;
};

void insert(struct mylist *list, int value)
{
    struct mynode *n = malloc(sizeof *n);
    if (n == NULL) exit(1);
    *(int *)&n->value = value;  // Ugly trick to handle constness :-(
    n->next = NULL;
    n->prev = list->tail;    

    if (list->tail == NULL)
    {
        // First node
        list->head = n;
        list->tail = n;
    }
    else
    {
        // Add to the tail

        ... this part I leave to you ...
    }
}

void print_list_inorder(struct mynode *n)
{
    while(n)
    {
        ... add code to print value of n ...

        n = n->next;
    }
}

void free_list(struct mynode *n)
{
    ... add code to free all elements ...
}

int main(void)
{
    struct mylist list = {NULL, NULL};
    insert(&list, 30);
    insert(&list, 20);
    insert(&list, 50);
    insert(&list, 70);
    insert(&list, 10);

    print_list_inorder(list.head);

    free_list(list.head);

    return 0;
}
```

Once you have filled in the missing code and it's working, you take the next steps.

1. Read data from the file (instead of hard coded values)
2. Add a `print_list_sorted` function.

Comment: Thank you very much, you are my savior!